# The fundamental group of $SO(3)/SO(2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, topological-groups, fundamental-groups

Since the homogeneous space $M:=SO(3,\mathbb R)/SO(2,\mathbb R)$ is diffeomorphic to the sphere then $\pi_1(M)=0$. Now how to show the same for complex orthogonal groups. I mean if $X:=SO(3,\mathbb C)/SO(2,\mathbb C)$ then how to show that $\pi_1(X)=0$?

Comment: I know nothing of non-compact groups.  Is $SO(n)$ the maximal compact subgroup of $SO(n,\mathbb{C})$?  If so, you can probably use the Iwasa decomposition to see this.

Comment: @JasonDeVito yes I think it is. Thanks !